# How to set PrimeUI Datatable column width

Tags: javascript, css, prime-ui

How to set PrimeUI Datatable column width?
I have tried this code("http://www.primefaces.org/primeui/datatable.html"), it is working fine but i want to set width of column, please help me
Thx in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add width to

> .pui-datatable thead th, .pui-datatable tbody td, .pui-datatable tfoot td

class?

```
Edit:

.pui-datatable thead th:nth-child(1),
.pui-datatable tbody td:nth-child(1),
.pui-datatable tfoot td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 50px;
}

.pui-datatable thead th:nth-child(2),
.pui-datatable tbody td:nth-child(2),
.pui-datatable tfoot td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: It is working but i want set width of particular column.How can i set it for ex- 1st Column width:50px, 2nd column width:100px, thx in advanced

Comment: I've edited my answer. Remove the width you've added now and add these classes.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the headerStyle option in the columns array.

{field: 'view', headerText: 'View', content: createEditButton, **headerStyle**: "width:8%"},

I haven't been able to find the complete options list for the columns array so if anyone knows where it is please post it!

Comment: http://primefaces.org/primeui/#datatable

scroll down to the discussion on Column array.  it's hidden in the "Datasource" subtopic.  sometimes i wish the primefaces documentation was as stellar as their products :-)